# How to add button to system-managed ConnectionService call screen?

Tags: android, voip

Is there a way to add button to system-managed ConnectionService call screen? For example I need a button to start an activity over the call screen.

[image]

Comment: Question about this: does this system managed voip app reroute ALL incoming phone calls (even if from a landline) to be answered through your voip app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it's not possibile to change other Activitie's content without some framework like Xposed or Magisk, but those requires Root Permissions.